# Meteor collection filtering collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection of say four objects

```
[obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4]
```

What is a good way to implement a filter logic by a single flag where when it's true, I get

```
[obj1, obj2 obj3]
```

and when it's false, I get

```
[obj1, obj2, obj4]
```

I'm thinking this for quite a while and I am not able to came up with a good solution with only one flag.

---

My flat is student = true/false

here is what I have tried

```
obj1 = {};
obj2 = {};
obj3 = {student: true};
obj4 = {student: false};

var studentFlag; // Set this flag

Collection.find({$or: [{student: {$exists: false}}, {student: studentFlag}]}).fetch();
```

I am expecting when studentFlag is true, my query gives me obj1, obj2, obj3 and when it's false, I get obj1, obj2, obj4. But my query ends up with Invalid selector

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer this question. What do the objects look like? How is the flag being set? Is this in a template? What have you tried?

Comment: Do you make studentFlag = true; anywhere or is it uninitialized?

Comment: @Sindis it's uninitialized, that's where I'm expecting student: {$exists: false} to give me obj1 and obj2

Comment: And with studentFlag set it works well? Probably Mongo query can't digest variable with no value

Comment: @Sindis Sorry it was a typo in my actual code, this query works sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

If your flag is either true or unset, you can simply do:

```
Collection.find({student: true}).fetch()
```

or

```
Collection.find({student: {$ne: true}}).fetch() // not true or unitialized
```